# How to add new item in front of the listview / windows forms

Tags: winforms, listview

I created a ListView and in my program I need to add items while my program is working, and every item must be on the top of the list until the new item is added. How can I do that?
I tried with ;

```
ListView.Item.Add(0, item);
```

but its not working/

The second question is; is it possible for one item to be always on the top of this list and can I upgreade its value somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to insert an item at the top you can use [Items.Insert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert.aspx) method to do that

```
ListView.Items.Insert(0, item);
```

For editing an items value in the ListView simply change it's value as follows

```
ListView.Items[listViewItemIndex].Text = "New name";
```

If you want to keep an item always on top simple have an if statement that inserts the new items in position 1 instead of 0. Make sure that the number of items in the ListView is at least one or you will get an exception.

Comment: thank You, it almost worked. second part cannot update my value, but I will do that in a different way.

Comment: i did it that way :
ListView.Items[0].Text = "new name";

Comment: That should work. What view type are you using ? Details or other ?

Comment: It should be working which means I might need a bit of the code you are using in order to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: 1st part is working, and the second I solved using ListView.Items[0]Text = " " ; so Thank You for Your help :)